# Setting the background colour/highlight colour for a given string range using Core Text

Tags: iphone, ios, highlight, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have some text laid out using Core Text in my iPhone app. I'm using `NSAttributedString` to set certain styles within the text for given ranges.

I can't seem to find an attribute for setting a background / highlight colour, though it would seem it is possible. I couldn't find an attribute name constant that sounded relevant and the documentation only lists:

```
kCTCharacterShapeAttributeName
kCTFontAttributeName
kCTKernAttributeName
kCTLigatureAttributeName
kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
kCTForegroundColorFromContextAttributeName
kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName
kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName
kCTStrokeColorAttributeName
kCTSuperscriptAttributeName
kCTUnderlineColorAttributeName
kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
kCTVerticalFormsAttributeName
kCTGlyphInfoAttributeName
kCTRunDelegateAttributeName
```

Craig Hockenberry, developer of Twitterrific has said publicly on Twitter that he uses Core Text to render the tweets, and Twitterrific has this background / highlight that I'm talking about when you touch a link.

[image]

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be fantastic, thanks.

**Edit:** Here's a [link to the tweet](http://twitter.com/chockenberry/status/15078309180215296) Craig posted mentioning "Core text, attributed strings and a lot of hard work", and the [follow up](http://twitter.com/chockenberry/status/15080379799052289) that mentioned using CTFrameSetter metrics to work out if touches intersect with links.

Comment: This is not an answer but can you use the screenshot option in the Organiser window of XCode or does that cancel touches as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I had to use the Core Text metrics methods (getting the range, bounds, origins of lines etc) to calculate the bounding rectangle of the link. Once I had a rect for each line the link spanned, I drew the background into the context before redrawing the text above it.

Seems like a hell of a lot of work, but it works.

Comment: Hi Jasarien,
 Can you show how to use those metrics?.I am very new to core text.It will be very helpful. I am trying on my own too.

Comment: Try this quick presentation, it's very useful. http://www.slideshare.net/DJune/text-layout-with-core-text

Comment: I think it would be nicer if you provided the solution you found.

Comment: The solution I ended up with is here https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 6, I think you can get the effect you're looking for with: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName. Such as:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:selectedRange];
```

Comment: This does not draw any BackgroundColor when using CTFrameDraw and CTFramesetterCreateFrame

Comment: I don't think this attribute has a equal attribute for CTAttributedString